# How to use ngx_pagespeed module on folder only

Tags: nginx, config, pagespeed

i am struggling around to get pageSpeed working on some subfolders only. My own code is already optimized, so that pageSpees isnt neccessary there.

But the folders /forum /dashboard and /blog are running different kind of software which i want to get optimized by pageSpeed.

i tried pagespeed = off; globally and pagespeed = on; inside the locations /forum /dashbaord, etc. but without success. It just works for the entire domain which isnt what i want it to do.

Do you have any idea how to set up nginx config to controll pageSpeed for some subfolders only while leaving the rest of that domain untouched?

THanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your config?

Comment: Hm, not without huge efforts, its several pages long. I 've build my own custom conf over years. If really needed i could strip my conf down to some neccessary things.

Comment: Sorry this configuration is 2000 lines long. 
There must be a simpler solution.

Can i set pageSpeed per location? If so, how?
I tried but it didnt work.

Comment: Create a simple example showing the problem

Comment: My problem is that it works only for the full server or not.
I cant control it based on location.
I want it to work only on /forum /dashboard and /blog but not on the rest of that domain.